# Splitting user input by one space for the first two words, then storing the remaining phrase (C++)

Tags: c++, string, parsing, substring

Right now I'm trying to, and as the title says, find a way to split a string in a weird way.

Lets say the input looks like:
`1234.5/N 1222.2/W Taco Tuesday`

And the input given for the first two words separated by spaces will always be in the format #.#/(N/S/W/E)

The problem I'm having is with the last word. This word can be as many spaces as it wants to be and is only "terminated" by a newline.

My first try was doing:

```
std::string input1; // number/Letter
std::string input2; // number/Letter
std::string input3; // word
std::cin >> input1 >> input2 >> input3;
```

The problem is, obviously is that if input 3 has a space in it, cin won't capture anything past that last space.

I thought about using getline(cin, input), but I realized I would get a single string with everything in it, instead of 3 separate strings. I believe this would be more challenging to extract the numbers out of the first two (probably by using find(/)), somehow keeping the letter after the slash, then moving to the next number, extracting that, keeping the letter after, and finally getting the rest of the phrase, minus the letter after the slash.

Also I would have to store the numbers in separate variable for calculations, take note of the letter used, and keep the last phrase.

Is there any reasonably elegant way to do this using std::string or at the very least is there just some way to at least extract the first two words and then store the remaining phrase into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read first two words with `cin` and then use `getline`:

```
cin >> input1 >> input2;
getline(cin, input3);
```